# Why set<string>::iterator cannot use as key of map?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator, key

I have a piece of code like this:

```
set<string>::iterator it1;
set<string>::iterator it2;
pair<set<string>::iterator,bool> ret;

set<string> s;
ret = s.insert("bbbb1");
it1 = ret.first;

ret = s.insert("bbbb2");
it2 = ret.first;

map<set<string>::iterator, set<string>::iterator> m;

m.insert(make_pair(it1,it2));
```

but the last line "m.insert(make_pair(it1,it2));" failed..

Comment: Using iterators as map keys is a terrible idea (because any iterators that subsequently get invalidated could cause undefined behaviour). Don't do it. :-(

Comment: @Chris:  Iterators into a `std::set` are rarely invalidated.

Comment: @James: True, but if items get removed off the set, the iterators corresponding to those items would be. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::set` iterators are not random access iterators so they are not less-than comparable.

The type that you use as a key in a `std::map` must be able to be sorted using a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).  By default, `std::map` uses `<` to order keys.  You can change this behavior by providing a comparator when you define the type of the `std::map`.  You'll probably want to perform some relational comparison using the object pointed to by the iterator.